# In c++ Windows API resize window during runtime?

Tags: winapi, resize, window, height

How do you resize a global hwnd variable during runtime when a button is clicked?

Or just any way to resize the window during runtime.
i.e.

```
HWND hwnd; //global
int buttonid = 250; // an id for a button
//also global


int WINAPI wWinMain(/*blah blah blah */) {


//blah blah blah

hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    L"WindowClass",
    L"Window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    300, 275,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL
    );

    HWND mybutton = CreateWindow(
    L"BUTTON",
    L"Button",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
    14, 13,
    250, 200,
    hwnd,
    (HMENU)buttonid,
    hInstance,
    NULL
    );

//blah blah blah

}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lparam) {

switch(uMsg) {

 case WM_COMMAND:
 if(buttonid==wParam) {
 //this is where i want the code for resizing hwnd so when you click the
 //button it resizes the window
 }



}

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MoveWindow` or `SetWindowPos` (though the latter is more useful if you want to do more than just resize it).

In both cases, you can specify not only the position of the top-left corner, but also the position of the bottom-right corner, so if you leave the top-left corner as-is, and move the bottom-right, you resize the window without "moving" it.

Answer (score 8):

```
SetWindowPos(yourhwnd,0,0,0,newWidth,newHeight,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```

Or if you want to move and resize you can use the older MoveWindow function