# Resize windows using Java or C#

Tags: c#, java, windows, forms, resize

I'd like to create an application where I can resize Windows forms.

I can iterate through windows and get certain properties like so for example:

[How to iterate through window elements using JNA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045548/how-to-iterate-through-window-elements-using-jna)

I've found similar ones, but can I resize and relocate these windows rather than just getting their attributes like title and rect? I'd like to sort all visible windows as a tile but I can't figure  out how I can manipulate their position.

For example, I want to grab and resize Total Commander and Notepadd++ (the 2 visible windows) to be on the left and right half of the screen.

Is it possible? If anyone can show me a snippet I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to [enumerate](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/183009) all window instances in system and call proper WinAPI function like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609486/in-c-windows-api-resize-window-during-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

**C#:** You can obtain all the windows you can use this code:

```
  internal static class WindowsEnumeratorNativeMethods {
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     internal delegate Boolean EnumerationCallback(IntPtr handle, IntPtr parameter);

    [DllImport("User32.dll",
               CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
               ExactSpelling = true,
               EntryPoint = "EnumWindows",
               CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
               SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern Boolean EnumWindows(EnumerationCallback lpEnumFunc,
                                               IntPtr lParam);

  }

  ...

  List<IntPtr> handles = new List<IntPtr>();

  WindowsEnumeratorNativeMethods.EnumWindows(
    (h, p) => {
      handles.Add(h);
      return true;}, 
    IntPtr.Zero);
```

Next you should find out the required windows (Notepad++ etc). You can do it
by looking for windows' captions (see **GetWindowText** API function); to move/size 
the window use **SetWindowPos** API function.

While implementing API wrappers, you may find this useful:

http://www.pinvoke.net/